# How to skip footer page numbering for the first 4 pages in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How to skip footer page numbering for the first 4 pages in Word 2007?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

insert a section break after page 4 and modify the footer in the first section accordingly; the footer in the second section may not be connected with its predecessor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Klaus-Dieter Ost's answer (add a Section Break; note that I think also it must be a page-breaking type, not "continuous"): I think you need to deselect the **Link to Previous** option when editing the first footer of the new section (ie, page 5) - this makes the footers in the two section in to two distinct sets to edit seperately.

I don't have W2007 to hand (W2003 on this machine) so I can't tell you where the option is unfortunatly.